# Make shadows visible only in reflections

Tags: camera, shadows, reflection

I want to make the shadows of a mesh only show up in the reflection of another mesh. Invisible to the camera.
Imagine a ghost that appears only on mirrors. His shadow would only be visible in the mirror.

Comment: yes I don't know if it's doable with the Light Path node, of course you can do it in the Compositor